# how to increase the chunk size when sending an http stream-upload request through request.post and receiving it through fastapi

Tags: python, async-await, python-requests, stream, fastapi

This is fastapi http side:

```
from fastapi import Request
import aiofiles

@app.post('/upload')
async def upload(request: Request):
    try:
        filename = request.headers['filename']
        async with aiofiles.open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            async for chunk in request.stream():
                await f.write(chunk)
    except Exception:
        return {"message": "There was an error uploading the file"}
 
    return {"message": f"Successfuly uploaded {filename}"}
```

this is the request side:

```
import requests
import time

with open("images/1.png", "rb") as f:
    data = f.read()

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload'
headers = {'filename': '1.png'}

start = time.time()
resp = requests.post(url=url, data=data, headers=headers)
end = time.time() - start

print(f'Elapsed time is {end} seconds.', '\n')
print(resp.json())
```

I spend a lot of time on this part:

```
async with aiofiles.open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    async for chunk in request.stream():
        await f.write(chunk)
```

I uploaded 256MB of file and I saw that the size of chunk of every call to request.stream() gives me 256k chunk of data (on my system)
which means I will have to run `f.write(chunk)` around 10 times.
I was wondering if there is a way to increase chunk size to 1MB so I can reduce the number of writes.
My target is to improve the performance by using stream vs regular upload:

```
from fastapi import File, UploadFile
import aiofiles

@app.post("/upload")
async def upload(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    try:
        async with aiofiles.open(file.filename, 'wb') as f:
            while contents := await file.read(1024): # async read chunk
                await f.write(contents)
    except Exception:
        return {"message": "There was an error uploading the file"}
    finally:
        await file.close()

    return {"message": f"Successfuly uploaded {file.filename}"}
```

which is very slow.

Answer (score 1):

In you request side, you can try

```
def gen_file_stream():
    with open(file_name, "rb") as f:
        while True:
            data = f.read(1024*1024)
            if not data:
                break
            yield data
resp=requests.post(url,data=gen_file_stream())
```

It may set your stream size in the chunk and help reduce your file operations

Comment: I tried using your code and it doesnt work, it raises an exception

Comment: Where do you get the exception and what is the content?

Comment: ok by bad it works thanks, I forgot to add () to gen_file_stream

Comment: Hi Yuqi Wang, I checked the chunk size in the server side and the chunk size remains 64k, even though I tried like you to send 1MB, so it seems that your code under the hood divide the stream into 64k, Im wondering if requests package has something to do with it.

Comment: @tamarlev it is almost certain that httplib has something to do with it. See more in this [issue](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/2181)